# ASP MVC2: How to wrap every 3 items in model with a div

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, foreach

Need to wrap every 3 items in the model in a row.

Currently have:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i <= Model.Count()/3; i++ ) { %>
<div class="row row-md">
    <div class="content-normal">

        <% foreach (var challenge in Model) { %>
                <div class="grid grid-col-3up">
                    <div class="mod mod-games">
                        <div class="mod-hd">
                            <h5 class="heading heading-mod heading-mod-5up heading-muted">Week 1</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mod-box-banner">
                            <div class="mod-banner-box">
                                <% if (challenge.Completed) { %>
                                    <img src="assets/images/completed-banner.png" alt="" class="mod-completed-banner"/>
                                <% } %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mod-box mod-relative ">
                                <% if (challenge.Completed) { %> 
                                    <img src="assets/images/medal-game.png" alt="" class="mod-medal-game" />
                                    <span class="mod-game-entries"><%= challenge.Entries%> Entries Earned</span>
                                    <img src="assets/images/games-burst.png" alt="" class="mod-box-img">
                                <% } else { %>
                                    <img src="<%= challenge.Image %>" alt="" class="mod-box-img" />
                                <% } %>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mod-hd">
                            <h4 class="heading heading-mod heading-mod-3up heading-muted"><%= challenge.ChallengeTitle%></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mod-hr">
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mod-bd">
                            <p><%= challenge.ShortDescription%></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mod-btn no-pad">
                            <a href="<%= challenge.ChallengeUrl %>"class="btn">
                            Play 
                            <% if (challenge.Completed) { %>
                                    Again
                            <% } %>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mod-btn">
                            <a href="#" class="btn">Share</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  

                <% } %>  
    </div>
</div>
<% } %>
```

The first foreach throws an OverFlowException.

Comment: christopher, seems like you're using a `foreach` when you should be using a `for(var i = 0; i <= Model.Count()/3; i++ )`

Comment: Hi Dave! I turned it into a for loop, this is creating 3 copies of my 6 objects though, whereas I want to wrap every 3 objects in my model in a div(s)

Comment: convert to indexes Model[i*3], Model[i*3 + 1], Model[i*3 + 2],

Comment: Can you post that as an answer with a little more info? First time playing around with models in MVC2. Thanks for your help!

Comment: answer posted. check it out and LMK about the concept. it is NOT a complete implementation yet.

Comment: Your views are suspectible to XSS and HTML-injection. Please use `<%= Html.Encode( str ) %>` instead of `<%= str %>`.

Comment: Ended up using a Mod operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <% 

                int ChallengeCt = -1;
                foreach (var challenge in Model){
                    ChallengeCt++;


                    if ((ChallengeCt) % 3 == 0)
                    {


                        %>

    <div class="row row-md">
        <div class="content-normal">


                        <%
                    }

    // Content here

    <%             
        if ( ( ChallengeCt + 1) % 3 == 0)
                {

                   %>
    </div>
</div>

                   <%
                }
     %>  

                    <% } %>
```